# Use MySQLi Prepared Statement to Enter Dynamic, Multiple Rows into Database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have created a HTML form where users would submit their name, email, and language skills. Since a user may speak more than one language, user will be able to generate additional rows by clicking an "add" button.

The form will then be submitted and entered into a MySQL database. I'm using two tables to hold the received data, whereas the user-id in the first table will be auto_incremented:

```
| (user-id) | name | email|
| user-id | language | proficiency|
```

Now I'm trying to write the PHP code, which looks something like this:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$add_table1 = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO table1 (name, email) VALUES (?, ?)");
$add_table2 = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO table2 (user_id, language, proficiency) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

$add_table1->bind_param("ss", $name, $email);
$add_table1->execute();
$user-id = $mysqli->insert_id;

foreach($_POST['language'] as $index => $language) {
    $index = intval($index);
    $language = mysql_real_escape_string($language);
    $proficiency = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['proficiency'][$index]);
    $add_table2->bind_param("iss", $user-id, $language, $proficiency);
    $add_table2->execute();
}
$add_table1->close();
$add_table2->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

The table should look like this

```
| 1 | Mark | mark@me.com |
| 2 | Sue  | sue@me.net |

|1 | English | perfect |
|1 | Spanish | awesome |
|2 | English | great |
|2 | French | ok |
|2 | Korean | fluent |
```

However, with my code table 1 looks fine, but table 2 looks like this

```
| 1 |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |
```

Can somebody help? Thanks!

Comment: Why you're using mysql_real_escape_string here?

Comment: Voting to close as not a real question. Asking people for help with the code that never works due to syntax errors makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I should point out is that you don't use `mysql_real_escape_string` with prepared statements.

Another thing is that `$user-id` is not a valid variable name. You can't use a hyphen.

**Edit:**

It's a good thing to turn on error reporting and to output `mysqli`/`mysqli_stmt::$error` when anything fails. Most problems can be resolved with these.

Comment: Do you think the problem lies in mysql_real_escape_string? I'll take it out and see if it works. Yes, $user-id is actually just $userid; I put a dash in there to make it more readable (which is stupid:()

Comment: @nubicurio So downvote was because you posted a variable with invalid name that you "clarified" without saying so and because you were advised not to use mysql_real_escape_string with MySQLi combined with prepared statements? You actually got a good piece of advice with this answer, I suggest you listen to it.

Comment: Let me see if I can find out how to output my mysqli errors... I'm not sure I know what you meant with "-1 for what, exactly"...

Comment: Your Common Sense is obviously a "common sense" police. Why not tell me what the actual problem is instead of just voting people down that are genuinely trying to help? @MichaelRushton thanks for your advice; I didn't vote you down, I think Your Common Sense did.

Answer (score 1):

Your php mysqli code looks pretty good. Are you sure you are retreiving correctly the POST values? int the foreach loop print $language and $proficiency before executing the queries